# Why does the Filler item tell me to tilt the system?

Tags: tetris-axis

In vs. modes with items turned on, the Filler item (that's what I call it, its icon is green with six blocks) causes all the blocks in the player's field to disconnect and fall down, filling in all the holes and leaving an emptier grid of nicely-stacked blocks.

The thing is, using a Filler causes a prompt to appear that says to tilt the 3DS - and then it disappears almost instantly, unlike the "blow" and "touch screen" prompts which remain for several seconds when their relevant items are used. I try to tilt the 3DS just after I hit the button but it doesn't seem to have any effect. What is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the game wants you to make gravity let the tiles fall down. So, for that purpose, you have to tilt the device from horizontal to vertical.

Now, in the mind of the game developer, gravity pulls those tiles down towards the bottom edge of the screen (which is now roughly pointed to the floor) - because, hey, before you tilted it, gravity just pulled them *into* the screen, right? Well, not right.

Usually, at least from my experience, people do what the word "handheld" implies: They hold it in their hand, rather than putting it on a table. So, "normally", people would already have tilted it towards them. This causes the game to instantly recognize it as already tilted, and as such makes the message disappear immediately.

Comment: Yep this is it; it assumes that "flat" is the default position. Holding it flat before using the Filler makes the icon wait until you tilt upwards to drop the blocks down, and apparently it also lets you throw the tiles to the left or right side of the grid by tilting sideways (from flat).

Answer (score 1):

Filler/Cascade (Cascada in Spanish) causes the blocks to drop down filling the slots below them. You can tilt the Nintendo 3DS System so it pushes the blocks to the Left or Right*. I tilt the System before I use the item so that it triggers automatically, which saves a lot of time.

*I tilt the system at least 90 degrees left or right, but I think at least 45 degrees should do.